# Automatically publish a new batch for an exiting HIT in MTurk

Tags: automation, mechanicalturk

I have a fully configured HIT on MTurk and need to publish batches for this HIT in fixed intervals for a longer period of time.  Of course, doing this manually is tiring and also error-prone because the batches need to be posted at specific times of the day.  Are there any scripts that I could use to achieve this?

I had a look at Amazon's command line tools but they seem to be cumbersome to use and Amazon also doesn't support them anymore.

If the solution involves some programming, that's fine.  I also know how to use cronjobs.

Comment: How do you publish these HITs?  You could automate the process using something like selenium or a combination of cURL and php, or beautiful soup + python.  I mean, you could mix and match a lot of tools..  The best solution is really based on what you need to do in order to publish your HITs.  I would probably go the selenium route since you can definitely get the job done that way, but without more information about how you publish the HITs, I cannot say for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I set up HITs using Amazon's web interface.  I didn't know about selenium and yes, that looks like it could be a solution.  However, I'd prefer a solution that makes use of Amazon's HTTP API because that is probably more robust.

Comment: You should include all of this in your question to get more relevant answers.  If Amazon has an API to publish the batches, where is the documentation? Could you provide the link so we know what you are working off of? What methods are you using from their API in order to attempt this?

Comment: Sorry for not including this information.  I wasn't even aware that browser automation is a thing, so I could not say that I don't want to use it.  In the meantime, I think I found out how the API can be used.  I will test it and post the answer later if it works.  Thanks again.

Comment: No need to be sorry.  It really doesn't matter to me very much, I just figure I would help you get the best answer possible.  Other people who provide answers will need that type of info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really do your homework before posting here.  But since you are my former self, I will be generous and help you out.  A little bit of googling shows that there is a really nice Python library for interacting with MTurk.  It's called [Boto](https://github.com/boto/boto).  The [documentation](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/mturk.html) is a little terse but there is a good tutorial that helps you make your first steps: http://www.toforge.com/2011/04/boto-mturk-tutorial-create-hits/

Here is an example showing how easy it is to use this library:

```
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection

ACCESS_ID ='your access key'
SECRET_KEY = 'your secret key'
HOST = 'mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com'

mtc = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                      host=HOST)

print mtc.get_account_balance()
```

Once you have a script that creates a new HIT, you can use the crontab command (available on Linux/Unix and perhaps OS X) to automatically start this script at specific intervals.

Comment: Bahahaha, greatest. answer. ever.

Comment: Just use TurkPrime's microbatch feature. It will automate the entire process.